# floreant POS : error in building jar file using maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I have downloaded source code of FLOREANT POS from official site,  and tried to built the project using maven. It requires two Commands mvn clean & mvn pacakage , when I tried to use these it gives me following error

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:cr
eate (default) on project floreantpos: Cannot get the revision information from
the scm repository :
[ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command. svn: E155007: 'E:\POS\floreantpos
-code-452-trunk' is not a working copy
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (default) on project florea
ntpos: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository :
Exception while executing SCM command.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot get the revisi
on information from the scm repository :
Exception while executing SCM command.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision(CreateMojo.java:785)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute(CreateMojo.java:465)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Exception while executing SCM comm
and.
        at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.
java:63)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.AbstractSvnScmProvider.executeComma
nd(AbstractSvnScmProvider.java:388)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.AbstractSvnScmProvider.info(Abstrac
tSvnScmProvider.java:411)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.info(CreateMojo.java:818)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision(CreateMojo.java:754)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: svn: E155007: 'E:\POS\floreantpos-
code-452-trunk' is not a working copy
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.svnjava.command.info.SvnJavaInfoCom
mand.executeSingleInfoCommand(SvnJavaInfoCommand.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.svnjava.command.info.SvnJavaInfoCom
mand.executeInfoCommand(SvnJavaInfoCommand.java:71)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.svnjava.command.info.SvnJavaInfoCom
mand.executeCommand(SvnJavaInfoCommand.java:48)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.
java:59)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155007: 'E:\POS\floreantpo
s-code-452-trunk' is not a working copy
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorMana
ger.java:64)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorMana
ger.java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java
:1886)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java
:1777)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.readConflicts(SVNWCDb
.java:3308)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.readConflicts(SVNWCDb
.java:3281)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.opReadTreeConflict(SV
NWCDb.java:2723)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgGetInfo.run(SvnNgGetInfo.
java:72)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgGetInfo.run(SvnNgGetInfo.
java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNg
OperationRunner.java:20)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperati
onRunner.java:20)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactor
y.java:1149)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2485)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.svnjava.command.info.SvnJavaInfoCom
mand.executeSingleInfoCommand(SvnJavaInfoCommand.java:88)
        ... 30 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

[image]

and here is my POM.xml File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.floreantpos</groupId>
    <artifactId>floreantpos</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.code.sf.net/p/floreantpos/code/trunk</connection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>floreantpos</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>filters</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.floreantpos.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>config/ i18n/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>resources/META-INF/mvn-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="prepare phase" />
                                <unzip src="database/derby-server/posdb.zip" dest="${project.build.directory}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-1.4-build${buildNumber}.zip" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-bin/${project.build.finalName}"></zip>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-antrun-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.6,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ecs</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecs</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>foxtrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>foxtrot</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jpos</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
            <version>110</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jpos</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpos-controls</artifactId>
            <version>110</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.metawidget.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>metawidget-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.xeoh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspf.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.authorize</groupId>
            <artifactId>anet-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jide-oss</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>us.fatehi</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnetictrackparser</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-repo</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/local-lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I am not sure either its a plugin dependency error OR my Code Error

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did a download of the sources, not a checkout from the tag. For that reason the buildnumber-maven-plugin can't detect the revision number. In this case it should be good enough to skip it by adding `-Dmaven.buildNumber.skip` to the commandline arguments, based of [skip](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#skip) docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the same project floreantpos-code-1597-trunk with maven 3.3.3
and I just install J.D.K 1.8 -x86. After that I edit pom.xml by removing  following lines:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</plugin>`
```

Then I execute command line of maven or simply build or compile through an IDE:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin came from mojo.codehaus.org. I don't know if it's still active but checking this link says so: http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#skip

If you remove the plugin at pom.xml error will be gone.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```